# booklet package - text alignment

Tags: margins, booklet

I am trying to create a foldable booklet with the booklet package. However, the pages are not centered, i.e. that the midpoint of the document is not in the middle of the two pages. Hence, after folding, right pages have essentially no inner margin, whereas left pages have huge inner margin. Can this be fixed somehow?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[print]{booklet}
\setpdftargetpages
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]

Thanks!

Comment: When I compile your code, print it, and fold it in half, it looks perfectly centered to me.

Comment: You could also consider using `pdfpages` and `geometry` instead of `booklet`.

Comment: What are you compiling it with? I am using texlive 16.